# Writing logs to a file inside a flow and collecting inside a coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In an Android kotlin project I've created a singleton to take care of writing some log information to a file.

```
object LoggerManager: Tagged {

    init {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // collect
        }
        //...
    }

    fun LogFile(content: String) {
        val file = getNewFileName(appDirectory)

        if (!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile()

        if (file.exists() && file.canWrite()) {
            file.appendText("${getDate(false)} - $content \n")
            checkFileSize(file)
            checkNumberOfFiles()
           //here i would emit(true)
        } 
        else {
           //here i would emit(false)
        }
    }

    //....

}
```

I want this LogFile method to run in a coroutine and to keep the order of logs i've been told that I could create a flow that would be collected inside a coroutine created in init.

The LogFile function is called inside fuctions that are not `suspend`

for example it is used when i call methods from this class to create entries in my logcat

```
class AndroidLogger : Logger {

override fun v(tag: String, method: String, message: String) {
    Log.v(tag, "$method${getFinalMessage(message)}")
    LoggerManager.LogFile("V $tag | $method${getFinalMessage(message)}")
}

override fun d(tag: String, method: String, message: String) {
    Log.d(tag, "$method${getFinalMessage(message)}")
    LoggerManager.LogFile("D $tag | $method${getFinalMessage(message)}")
}

override fun i(tag: String, method: String, message: String) {
    Log.i(tag, "$method${getFinalMessage(message)}")
    LoggerManager.LogFile("I $tag | $method${getFinalMessage(message)}")
}

override fun w(tag: String, method: String, message: String) {
    Log.w(tag, "$method${getFinalMessage(message)}")
    LoggerManager.LogFile("W $tag | $method${getFinalMessage(message)}")
}

override fun e(tag: String, method: String, message: String) {
    Log.e(tag, "$method${getFinalMessage(message)}")
    LoggerManager.LogFile("E $tag | $method${getFinalMessage(message)}")
}

override fun wtf(tag: String, method: String, message: String, throwable: Throwable) {
    Log.wtf(tag, "$method${getFinalMessage(message)}", throwable)
    LoggerManager.LogFile("WTF $tag | $method${getFinalMessage(message)}")
}

private fun getFinalMessage(message: String) = if (message.isEmpty()) EMPTY_STRING
else " - $message"
```

}

I'm not very experienced with Flows.
Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. What do you want to collect in a coroutine? Do you need to create a logging function that may be invoked concurrently?

Comment: I want that method to emit a boolean, and collect it on the coroutine created in init

Comment: Well, you can create a property like this: `private val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>()`, then emit from `LogFile()` with: `flow.tryEmit(false)`. But it really sounds like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Actually, you would need to provide `extraBufferCapacity` param to `MutableSharedFlow`.

Comment: What possible reason would there be for both emitting and collecting from this same singleton? Seems like a convoluted alternative to directly calling a function.

Comment: I believe what OP needs is to schedule logging operations concurrently and asynchronously and then execute them sequentially. Pretty common pattern when dealing with IO/resources, usually implemented with `BlockingQueue`, `Channel` or single-threaded executor. Someone told OP that it could be done with flows, which is technically possible e.g. using `MutableSharedFlow`, but this is probably not the best choice @Tenfour04